# Is it possible to remove standard Menu Drawers from bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus.remove?

Tags: interface

I want to know how to remove standard menu drawers from the  bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus.remove(drawer_function).
I want to remove File|Edit|Render|Window|Help and replace the entire menu stack.

I know how to remove custom menu drawers.
Just cant seem to find a reference to the existing ones.

Comment: You want to do it dynamically with an add-on or to remove it "forever" ?

Comment: dynamically with add-on..